# Use a pipe as a delimiter in XSL for Excel

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have XML nodes that have pipes in the data. How can I use XSL to tell Excel to use them as delimiters to separate the data into columns.

Example:
`<marcEntry tag="856" ind="41">|uhttp://spo.nmfs.noaa.gov/Circulars/CIRC294.pdf|zOnline version in PDF</marcEntry>`

Comment: You cannot use XSL to tell Excel anything. You can use it to transform the input into something Excel will recognize. If your processor supports XSLT 2.0, then use the `tokenize()` function to break the input string into a sequence of strings that you can process individually.

Comment: Ditto Michael's comment -- I don't think Excel has any built-in XSL processing.  It _is_ possible to use XSL to turn XML into a specific variety of XML that Excel understands natively (the Excel 2003 single-file XML output format), but that is an arduous process, and well beyond the scope of a single question on this site.